# create a permissions to restrict third party apps calling an activity android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-preferences

I am having two android apps signed with same certificate. Also i am using the activity of one app in other android app by specifying a name in "intent-filter" tag. But because of "intent-filter" tag any third party app can call my activity.

Since both the apps are having the same certificates signed, can i restrict other apps calling my activity by providing some permisions? Any suggestions on this would be helpful to me.

-Ron...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you could maybe remove the intent-filters if your activity is not meant to be used by other applications than yours ; why not use an explicit intent instead?
Thus your activity couldn't be created "by mistake" but only intentionally, ex :

```
Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(InvokingActivity.this, InvokedActivity.class);
startActivity(explicitIntent);
```

Then, to even prevent that from the outside, you could define your own custom permission and add it to your activity ; have a look at the [android:protectionLevel](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel) attribute of a permission, whose value can be "signature".

Comment: thanks for the response, i used intent-filter tag because one activity is getting shared btwn two apps. Also can you please post some example on how to use the android:protectionLevel="signature" for an activity?

Comment: Don't those 2 apps know the class to be called directly so you could use an explicit intent (see my example) instead of implicit (ie through intent filters)?

Comment: Actually, here the problem is i am having login activity that is shared. If i use explicit intent then after some time if i create a new app then i need to modify this explicit intent. So i used intent-filter tag so that i will only call the intent name from the apps. Now even i create a new app then just using the intent name will help me calling the login activity.

Comment: As for the use of permissions, see just there : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms You create a permission at package level with attribute android:protectionLevel="signature" + you declare it at package level with the uses-permission tag + you declare it at activity level with the android:permission attribute of the activity.

Comment: adding to the above comment, i think explicit intent will be called only from the same package. But my two apps are being developed as two different package and i dont want to mess up both by adding references. Is it possible to enforce android:protectionLevel from intent-filter tag? I think if it is possible then i will get a solution.

Comment: In the idea yes that should work, but see my previous comment about the use of tags and attributes in a custom permission.

Comment: Cool, your last comment will help me to get through this problem. I was looking for this android:permission tag. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @darma I did same thing, but now not able to laucnh my activity thruogh touch. Its getting launched only if i run as android app through eclipse